# spring jpa won't update new data

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I would like to update new data from request.

Request JSON data looks like this.

```
[{"media_id : 1, "path" : "some path", ...}, {"media_id : 2, "path" : "some path", ...}]
```

These primary keys already exist in database

So It will update those rows and It should be updated

But update sql on debug log only update old data

I checked out media object that It contains new data from request

But jpa still try update with old data

What is my mistake?

```
private List<Media> upsertMedia(SquarePostDetailResource postToUpsert) {

    List<Media> media = postToUpsert.getContent().getMedia();

    media.forEach((item) -> {
        item.setCreatedAt(item.getId() == null ? new Date() : item.getCreatedAt());
        item.setModifiedAt(new Date());
        item.setMember(Member.builder().id(postToUpsert.getMemberId()).build());
        item.setSquare(Square.builder().id(postToUpsert.getSquareId()).build());
        item.setSquarePost(SquarePost.builder().id(postToUpsert.getPostId()).build());
    });


    return (List<Media>) mediaRepo.save(media);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that updates inside foreach do not update the database, you can try the following.

```
private List<Media> upsertMedia(SquarePostDetailResource postToUpsert) {

    List<Media> media = postToUpsert.getContent().getMedia();
    List<Media> updatedMedia = new ArrayList<>();

    media.forEach((item) -> {
        item.setCreatedAt(item.getId() == null ? new Date() : item.getCreatedAt());
        item.setModifiedAt(new Date());
        item.setMember(Member.builder().id(postToUpsert.getMemberId()).build());
        item.setSquare(Square.builder().id(postToUpsert.getSquareId()).build());
        item.setSquarePost(SquarePost.builder().id(postToUpsert.getPostId()).build());
        updatedMedia.add(item);
    });


    return (List<Media>) mediaRepo.save(updatedMedia);
}
```

Comment: save method of spring data jpa will update database if primary key is defined. 
I can see update sql from the console log when save method is called.
but my problem is that the field that should be updated is old data not new data.

Comment: Do you mean that field modifiedAt does not have `new Date()` value in update statement?

Comment: You can also try `List<Media> media = postToUpsert.getContent().getMedia();` after for loop and before `mediaRepo.save(media);`.

Comment: I just noticed wrong point in my code by your comment. thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe I should update the answer for future reference, the last comment of getting the media list again after loop helped you?